# Using subprocess to read adb shell but I don't see any data returned from adb shell

Tags: python, console, subprocess, adb

After running **line 6** - it prints out an option to choose.
I choose option 3 in **line 8** and later I send value 10 in **line 10** to start logging a process.

I need help in understanding why I don't get any output from `adb` shell. How do I proceed further?.

```
import subprocess as sp
def test_logging():
    proc = sp.Popen(['adb', 'shell'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=0)
    time.sleep(1)
    proc.stdin.write("./data/TestApp -r 150\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    proc.stdin.write("3\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    proc.stdin.write("10\n")
    print("\n supposed to be logging")
    while True:
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        if output =='' and proc.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output.strip())
```

Comment: Just a note, your loop can just be replaced with `for line in proc.stdout:` and it will continue to iterate until the process exits. Is the `adb` output going to stderr? Have you checked `proc.stderr`?

Comment: @jordanm: No output from `proc.stderr` as well.